# Convergence of $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{1+x^2}$ when turning into a power series

Tags: integration, power-series, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I was attempting to solve the integral:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{1+x^2}dx$$

by means of power series. Countour integration reveals the answer as $\frac{\pi}{2e}$, but I wanted another way to do it by transforming $\cos x$ into a power series. This goes as follows:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{1+x^2}dx = \int_0^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(1+x^2)(2n)!}dx$$

I actually am not positive if this is justified (if someone is able to give some info on when and when this isn't justified, that'd be great. (Fubini's Theorem?), but I'm going to rearrange the sum and integral as follows:

$$= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^2}dx$$

However, this integral does not converge for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. What is the problem in this computation?

Comment: That switch is always justified for power series within the region of convergence. I think you should be able to find a statement to that effect in any calculus textbook

Comment: That's fair. I haven't seen that in a standard calculus textbook. What is the incorrect step, then? Clearly, we've arrived at a divergent integral on the last line.

Comment: Nothing you've done is incorrect, it's just that your series is an "indeterminate sum" of infinities. The result is that *if* the resulting sum converges, then it must match the original integral

Comment: As an analogy, consider
$$
\int_1^\infty \left[x - \frac{x^3 - 1}{x^2}\right]\,dx.
$$
We could split this into $\int_1^\infty x\,dx - \int_1^\infty \frac{x^3 - 1}{x^2}\,dx$, but of course the resulting integrals don't converge

Comment: Technically the result would not be there, but the result that you *would* find is about the antiderivative $\int_0^x \frac{\cos(t)}{1 + t^2}\,dt$ of your integrand, which is the function whose limit you're interested in computing.

Comment: Why do you want to do so? $\int \frac{x^{2 n}}{x^2+1} \, dx$ is a nightmare

Comment: @BenGrossmann I'm totally with you that the integral diverges.  I just don't know how a convergent integral turned into a divergent integral from a simple power series within the radius of convergence. If this happens, we just disregard it?

Comment: And @Raffaele It is a nightmare, but I was just experimenting with the integral. Just messing around. It's a simple "why not?" In particular, I thought it would be neat to get a nice series that evaluates to $\frac{\pi}{2e}$

Comment: Since $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cosh x}{1+x^{2}} \, \mathrm dx$ doesn't converge, Fubini's theorem is not satisfied.  However, Fubini's theorem only provides sufficient conditions for switching the order of limiting operations.  It doesn't provide necessary conditions.

Comment: @RandomVariable The integral is $\cos x$, not $\cosh x$

Comment: I know.  But $$\int_0^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left|\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(1+x^2)(2n)!} \right| \,  \mathrm dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!} \, \mathrm dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cosh x}{1+x^{2}} \, \mathrm dx \, , $$ which doesn't converge.  So Fubini's theorem is not satisfied.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the relationship immediately, I apologize. Thank you for clarifying; this makes it much clearer.